# Insert row into database using static or non-static method

Tags: php, object-oriented, comparative-review, database

I would like to know if there are any benefits of one of the following 2 methods which insert an object into a database

The first function calls the Model method statically, creating a new instance of the Insert function on the call.

```
foreach ($model_data as $data) {
    $row = \Models\ModelData::createRow($data, $u->dname, $w_reason, $comment);
    $insert = \Models\ModelData::Insert($row);
    $insert_obj = new \stdClass();
    $insert_obj->d_name = $data->{'Data Name'};
    $insert_obj->status = $insert;
    $insert_array[] = $insert_obj;
}
```

This version of the function calls the Model method non-statically.

```
foreach ($model_data as $data) {
    $row = \Models\ModelData::createRow($data, $u->dname, $w_reason, $comment);
    $insert_result = $row->Insert();
    $insert_obj = new \stdClass(); 
    $insert_obj->d_name = $data->{'Data Name'};
    $insert_obj->status = $insert_result;
    $insert_array[] = $insert_obj;
}
```

With the Model method being called non-statically, there is no need for an argument to be passed in.

```
public function Insert(): bool
```

But with the Model being created via a static method, it requires the argument.

```
public static function Insert(MyObject $object): bool
```

Is there a major benefit to one of these over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think, in "Object-oriented programming", it makes perfect sense to explicitly craft your scripts to handle objects.  The ability to chain methods together can help to make your code less verbose.
2. `$row` and `$insert_result` are single-use variables, so I would not bother declaring it.
3. Rather than forming an individual object, then declaring the properties, then pushing the object into the result array, I recommend the more brief syntax of populating the object inside of the push syntax.

Suggested, untested code:

```
foreach ($model_data as $data) {
    $insert_array[] = (object) [
        'd_name' => $data->{'Data Name'},
        'status' => (\Models\ModelData::createRow($data, $u->dname, $w_reason, $comment))->Insert()
    ];
}
```

While the above snippet doesn't quite fit neatly in the Stack Exchange text area, it does comply with the recommended line width limits described by [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/).

Alternatively, if you prefer to declare `$row` to lessen the line width, then you can use:

```
foreach ($model_data as $data) {
    $row = \Models\ModelData::createRow($data, $u->dname, $w_reason, $comment);
    $insert_array[] = (object) [
        'd_name' => $data->{'Data Name'},
        'status' => $row->Insert()
    ];
}
```

Ultimately, unless you have a valid reason to have `Insert` as a static method, I'd not recommend it.  By the way, methods should start with a lowercase letter for PSR-12 compliance.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I'd like to follow up with a question to your statement "Ultimately, unless you have a valid reason to have Insert as a static method". What would a valid reason be for making Insert a static method?

Comment: Like "you _need_ to have a shortcut path to `Insert()` without going through the class constructor and declaring the object".  As a general rule, I don't use static methods unless it is valuable to circumvent non-static methods.  Typically you use OOP, so that you can manipulate objects.  I find static methods break up the flow that OOP affords.